# Java8: Is there a way to get an instance method reference from a class method reference?

Tags: java, java-8

If I have, for instance, an interface like this:

```
public interface FooBar<A, B> {
    B foo(A a);

    B bar(A a);
}
```

Is there a way to take a class-level method reference like `FooBar::bar` and get an instance method reference?

ie. if I have

```
FooBar myFooBarInstance;
BiFunction<FooBar<A, B>, A, B> barFunction = FooBar::bar;
```

is there any simple way to get a `Function<A,B>` instance that would match what I'd get if I defined

```
Function<A, B> myBarFunction = myFooBarInstance::bar;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want to do is called “partial function application” in the function programming world or just “binding a value to a parameter” in less functional terms. There’s no built-in method for that, but it’s easy to write your own:

```
public static <T,U,R> Function<U,R> bind(BiFunction<T,U,R> f, T t) {
    return u -> f.apply(t, u);
}
```

Then you can use it in your case:

```
FooBar<X,Y> instance=…;
BiFunction<FooBar<X,Y>,X,Y> barFunction=FooBar::bar;
Function<X,Y> myBarFunction=bind(barFunction, instance);
```

or just

```
// equivalent to myBarFunction=instance::bar
Function<X,Y> myBarFunction=bind(FooBar::bar, instance);
```

Note that the utility method is tight to the functional interfaces you are using, i.e. `Function` and `BiFunction`, not to the method references. It works for any `BiFunction`, be it implemented as method reference, lambda expression or ordinary class. But it will be useful only if you specifically need a `Function` instance, not for an arbitrary functional interface taking one parameter. You can convert a `Function` to another single-argument function type using `::apply` but using `bind(bifunc, value)::apply` doesn’t offer any benefit over `x -> bifunc.apply(value, u)` at the place where the instance is required.

So if you have to convert `BiFunction`s to `Function`s via binding a first argument very often, the utility method might be useful. Otherwise, just use a lambda expression in the context where the actual target type is present. Of course, you can write a similar method for other interfaces as well, but this will again only be useful if you need it for that specific interface often.

Regarding functions taking more parameters, since the Java API doesn’t provide such functional interfaces, you will have to define the appropriate interface yourself, which offers the option of providing the binding function directly in the interface as `default` methods, e.g.

```
interface MyFunc3<A,B,C,R> {
    R apply(A a, B b, C c);
    default BiFunction<B,C,R> bind(A a) {
        return (b, c) -> apply(a, b, c);
    }
}
interface MyFunc4<A,B,C,D,R> {
    R apply(A a, B b, C c, D d);
    default MyFunc3<B,C,D,R> bind(A a) {
        return (b, c, d) -> apply(a, b, c, d);
    }
}
```

then, if you have a function like

```
MyFunc4<U, W, X, Y, Z> func = …;
```

you can do something like

```
MyFunc3<W, X, Y, Z> f3 = func.bind(u);
```

or

```
BiFunction<X, Y, Z> f2 = func.bind(u).bind(w);
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation as usual, Holger. Hadn't considered simply adding a default method for binding an instance to a functional interface, but it's a really useful trick.

Answer (score 3):

I realized that the answer's pretty simple once I thought about it. I can do this:

```
Function<A, B> instanceFunction = (a)->barFunction.apply(myFooBar, a);
```

It gets really ugly if you have methods that take more than a couple parameters, but it works...

Comment: This works, but it's not very generic... 
Does anybody have a reasonably elegant way that's not dependent on knowing the method signature in advance? I know I can construct things with reflection, but it would be nice to know there was a nicer way.

Comment: Static typing requires that the types be known at compile time.  There is no way to do this generically without either generating byte code, or generating code and compiling it at runtime.  In Java , a better solution is to avoid needing to do this in the first place and write more specific code.  A more dynamic language could handle this but you get all the downsides of having a dynamic language.