# can i convert any lambda expression into method reference

Tags: java-8

I wonder if can i convert any lambda expression into method reference

for example:

if there is a lambda that execute method with 2 parameters (one of them is from outside)

```
.map( t -> removeFilesIfNessasary( externalObj, t ) )
```

can this also converted into method reference?

thanks

Comment: No, it cannot..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35938642/2711488

Comment: @Holger awesome, much better then what I have

Answer (score 3):

Well you could create a class, sort of like this:

```
class Remover {
     private final Object externalObj;

     public Remover(Object externalObj){
         this.externalObj = externalObj;
     }       

     public removeIf(int t){
         removeFilesIfNessasary( externalObj, t);
     }
}
```

and then declare this and use it:

```
Remover remover = new Remover(externalObj);

.map(remover::remove);
```

But seriously, this looks *really* weird; there has to be a compelling reason for you to do this (I can't think of one).

Comment: Up-vote first，maybe use a cury method is better. e.g:`cury(F2,arg1)`.

Comment: @holi-java can you provide an example may be? I sort of don't get it...

Comment: Hi, @Holger has already provided at the comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931134/java8-is-there-a-way-to-get-an-instance-method-reference-from-a-class-method-re/35938642#35938642